# Cannot delete supercolumn with cassandra-cli

Tags: cassandra, super-columns

```
[default@keyspace] get fv['user:/file.txt'];
=> (super_column=1365647977415,
     (column=6363, value=0000000000000001, timestamp=1368238637628082)
     (column=6c6d64, value=0000013f79344eb2, timestamp=1368238637628081)
     (column=7362, value=000000000000003a, timestamp=1368238637628083))
=> (super_column=1365653962252,
     (column=6363, value=0000000000000001, timestamp=1368238637727277)
     (column=6c6d64, value=0000013f798fbee6, timestamp=1368238637727276)
     (column=7362, value=0000000000000045, timestamp=1368238637727278))

del fv['user:/file.txt'][1365647977415];
column removed.

get fv['user:/file.txt'];
=> (super_column=1365647977415,
     (column=6363, value=0000000000000001, timestamp=1368238637628082)
     (column=6c6d64, value=0000013f79344eb2, timestamp=1368238637628081)
     (column=7362, value=000000000000003a, timestamp=1368238637628083))
=> (super_column=1365653962252,
     (column=6363, value=0000000000000001, timestamp=1368238637727277)
     (column=6c6d64, value=0000013f798fbee6, timestamp=1368238637727276)
     (column=7362, value=0000000000000045, timestamp=1368238637727278))
```

How is this possible? Comparator is ByteType, I used

```
assume fv comparator as LongType;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the column timestamp which was newer than now. Be careful, guys.

```
=> (super_column=1365647977415,
     (column=6363, value=0000000000000001, timestamp=1368238637628082)
```

1368238637628082 == Sat, 11 May 2013 02:17:17 GMT

Now is Thu, 11 Apr 2013 07:10:36 GMT